# Django app running on 8000 cant be reached from windows

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2

I am running a django app on `0.0.0.0:8000` on ec2.

I can access this app using wget, but the same url does not work form windows.

In my Security group I have added a rule to allow port range 8000 from source `0.0.0.0/0`.

Here is the wget response. Most certainly a config issue. Any AWS EC2 experts there?

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-15-59:~$ wget 13.232.233.180:8000/events
--2020-09-03 11:05:24--  http://13.232.233.180:8000/events
Connecting to 13.232.233.180:8000... ^C
ubuntu@ip-172-31-15-59:~$ wget http://ubuntu@ec2-13-232-233-180.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/events
--2020-09-03 11:07:03--  http://ubuntu@ec2-13-232-233-180.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/events
Resolving ec2-13-232-233-180.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com (ec2-13-232-233-180.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com)... 172.31.15.59
Connecting to ec2-13-232-233-180.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com (ec2-13-232-233-180.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com)|172.31.15.59|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /events/ [following]
--2020-09-03 11:07:03--  http://ubuntu@ec2-13-232-233-180.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/events/
Reusing existing connection to ec2-13-232-233-180.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8000.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2319 (2.3K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘events’

events                                 100%[==========================================================================>]   2.26K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2020-09-03 11:07:03 (47.1 MB/s) - ‘events’ saved [2319/2319]
```

Comment: So you've got a django app running on an EC2 box, but are you using a web server and a domain?

Comment: using default amazon domain.

Comment: I am using default domain http://ec2-65-0-61-175.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/events/. The problem was with the rules in my security group. I fixed that and it woks now. Thanks